# Extract only value result find request from mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

i want to extract only the value from the domain document

```
import socket
from pymongo import MongoClient



client = MongoClient()
db = client.my_domains
collection = db.domain
document = collection.find({},{'domain': 1, '_id':0})


for d in document:
    print(d)
```

Result is :

```
{u'domain': u'301udns.info'}
{u'domain': u'idcay.com'}
```

How can extract only the value like 301udns.info for my example.
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: I guess you're trying to do a `d['domain']`?

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in document:
    print (d['domain'])
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thx !